# Join AR Model with Temp Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, temp-tables

I used the [Temping gem](https://github.com/jpignata/temping) in order to create a temp table.

I need to join the temping table I created with an AR model. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Here is the raw SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `example1` as t1 JOIN `example2` as t2 on t1.`book_name` = t2.`book_name` and t1.`author` = t2.`author` and t1.`date`= t2.`date`
```

In this case, example1 is the temp table (created via the temping gem), and example 2 is the actual AR model.

Answer (score 0):

As Temping create AR objects, I guess you could use something like:

```
Example1.joins("example2 ON example1.book_name = example2.book_name ... etc").find_all
```